# JSON Response includes function in PHP

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have one PHP code which has JSON response.

I need to separate the `['name' => $message->getName(), 'mes' => $message->getMes(), 'update_time' => $message->getUpdateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]` into a independent function.
When I need I can call it.

But, I don't know how to do.

this is my controller

```
/**
* @Route("/message/board/reset/{id}", name = "message_reset", requirements = {"id" = "\d+"})
*/
public function editMeg($id)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $message = $entityManager->find('MegBundle:message', $id);
    $UserN = $message->getName();
    $UserM = $message->getMes();
    return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => ['name' => $message->getName(), 'mes' => $message->getMes(), 'update_time' => $message->getUpdateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]]);
}
```

I hope this is reasonable and has ways to do it.

I appreciate any help.

I Heop it can like this

```
/**
     * @Route("/message/board/updata/{id}", name = "message_updata", requirements = {"id" = "\d+"})
     * @Method("PUT")
     */
    public function updataMeg(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $message = $entityManager->find('MegBundle:message', $id);
        $message->setMes($request->request->get("txtMes"));
        $entityManager->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => jsonreturn()]);
    }
    public function jsonreturn()
    {
        $json = 'name' => $message->getName(), 'mes' => $message->getMes(), 'update_time' => $message->getUpdateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `separate the array into an independent function`, can you elaborate what you are trying to do?

Comment: what is wrong with the way things are now?? how are you expecting it to be

Comment: @catcon  I have re-edited my question thank you.

Comment: @JayWadhwa I have re-edited my question thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I try the following code:

controller.php:

```
/**
* @Route("/message/board/updata/{id}", name = "message_updata", requirements = {"id" = "\d+"})
* @Method("PUT")
*/
public function updataMeg(Request $request, $id)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $message = $entityManager->find('MegBundle:message', $id);
    $message->setMes($request->request->get('txtMes'));
    $entityManager->flush();
    $message->toArray($message);
    return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => $message]);
}
```

entity.php

```
public function toArray($message)
{
    $this->message = array('name' => $message->getName(), 'mes' => $message->getMes(), 'update_time' => $message->getUpdateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}
```

and I get

> {"result":"ok","ret":{"message":{"name":"AAA","mes":"test","update_time":"2019-09-25 08:13:04"}}}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do this instead:

```
private function jsonreturn($message) {
  return ['name' => $message->getName(), 'mes' => $message->getMes(), 'update_time' => $message->getUpdateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
}
```

just pass the `$message` object to this function

Comment: That is right, but when I try it, It show **{"result":"ok","ret":{}}**. I Heop I can get response like this **{"result":"ok","ret":{"name":"AppelApple","mes":null,"update_time":"2019-09-20 12:24:46"}}**

Answer (score 0):

The format you require is `json` encoded, therefore, you can try the following code:

```php
private function jsonreturn($message) {
  echo json_encode(['name' => $message->getName(), 'mes' => $message->getMes(), 'update_time' => $message->getUpdateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
}
```

[json_encode php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: But when I try it, it show **{"result":"ok","ret":{}}** How to fix it? thank you

Comment: I have updated the code, please try using the updated code.

Comment: it still the same when I try your code and edit my controller  **return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => $message]);**  it show **{"result":"ok","ret":{}}**